# How do I call a secured page from my own AppEngine web-service?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

To send a HTML email I'd like to call a different URL of my own App,
to have the comfort of JSP for rendering the Email-content.

To execute the HTTP-call to my own app I first tried to use "http://localhost/emailreport" as URL, but that failed with a DNS-error.
Next I tried the external URL:

```
String appid = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAttributes()
   .get("com.google.appengine.runtime.default_version_hostname").toString();
appid = appid.substring(0, appid.indexOf('.'));
URL url = new URL("http://" + appid + ".appspot.com/emailreport");
```

This works, but only for pages without security-constraints in web.xml. My emailreport however needs to be secured.

Any Idea how to retrieve that page? Do I need to use a Service-Account-Key? Isn't there a simple trick?

ADDED:
I want to secure the pages by adding this to the web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SecureName</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/mytask</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Why not call your URL with https? Appspot.com supports it by default.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. http or https doesn't make a difference. AppEngine still requires authentication when I try to read my own app's page.

Comment: Requiring authentication and requiring https is different things. Which is it? Also, adding an HTTP call ads a lot of overhead, not sure how things are done in JSP but you'd normally just render it internally...

Comment: I need authorization (authentication is done by GAE). web.xml snipped added above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the following workaround:

Caller creates a secret token and stores it in MemCache and adds a header to the request.

Endpoint reads that header and compares it with the value in MemCache. If it matches, it processes the request, otherwise it returns a 401.